# Program closed unexpected in VS

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

When I try to add a website in a project I see this error :

"problem caused the program to stop working correctly. windows will close the program and notify you solution"

And I have to close the project or The project will be restarted from beginning.

I do this :

File > Add > New website

Web Location = HTTP > Localhost

OS : Win8 , IIS : Ver8 and VS 2010

Answer (score 0):

try this in VS:

1- go to Tools->Import and export settings->reset all settings.

or

2- update your visual studio to latest service pack.